# error on deploy a Safe on Sepolia with v1.4.1

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

i use all the info in here https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/tree/main/src/assets/v1.4.1 to deploy a new Safe on sepolia.

i use `createProxyWithNonce(address _singleton,bytes initializer,uint256 saltNonce)`
on the safeProxyFactory, for the params i put:

- _singleton i put the safeL2 address
- to compute the initializer i use the pack "setup" from safe_l2 abi

```go
safeL2abi.Pack("setup", owners, threshold, to, data, fallbackHandler, paymentToken, payment, paymentReceiver)
```

- and a big Int for the saltNonce

first is it the right one to use, if not what is it?
because i got an error on the singleton

```js
   constructor(address _singleton) {
        require(_singleton != address(0), "Invalid singleton address provided");
        singleton = _singleton;
    }
```

tx: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x1e22c80dcfa2a9072b2dd849b9ee651ce9f72d23b64afe3f7c2ad96c10ab9ad9

then to what will be the steps to calculate the future target address for the Safe?

Comment: What exactly is your error? It's not clear from your question what problem you're facing

Comment: yes @mikheevm the Safe created with that tx above
[https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x1e22c80dcfa2a9072b2dd849b9ee651ce9f72d23b64afe3f7c2ad96c10ab9ad9#eventlog](see log event)
 is not valid
[https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0xd550CD19844af57f570B2FaDa586B83d1D560060](see the Safe) if i query the version or getOwners to 0xd550CD19844af57f570B2FaDa586B83d1D560060 it doesn't return any values

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out. I haven't looked thoroughly into your error, but I can point you to our [protocol kit](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit), where there is class `SafeFactory` that exposes a `predictSafeAddress` method where a deterministic Safe address is calculated from your configuration.

Does this help?